# How can I use the 3dconnexion spacemouse mouse in Pythons vtk

Tags: python, mouse, vtk

I am reading an stl file and simply showing it on the Screen (and adding some results later). The turning and handling of the object is not really smooth.

It would be cool to get the 3dconnexion spacemouse to work in order to manipulate the objekt. Is it possible? How?

What do I have to add to the interactor?

Thank you for help

Okapi

```
import vtk

class VtkStl:

def __init__(self, filename):
    self.filename = filename
    self.vtkActor = vtk.vtkActor()

def addStl(self):
    reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
    reader.SetFileName(self.filename)
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    if vtk.VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5:
        mapper.SetInput(reader.GetOutput())
    else:
        mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort()) 
    self.vtkActor.SetMapper(mapper)

Bock_stl=VtkStl('d:\trial.stl')       
Bock_stl.addStl()

# Renderer
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(Bock_stl.vtkActor)

renderer.SetBackground(.2, .3, .4)
renderer.ResetCamera()

# Render Window
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)

# Interactor
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

# Begin Interaction
renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()

del renderWindow, renderWindowInteractor
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/3DConnexion_Devices_Support ?

Comment: I had a look at it, since I have to use Windows, and the mouse is running in other programms, the only thing that I have to do is: self.renderWindowInteractor.AddObserver('TDxMotionEvent',0), but is is not at all working?!

Comment: Have you compiled vtk with VTK_USE_TDx equals TRUE?

Comment: I have not compiled it at all, I am using the python libs of anaconda, but I have now tryed `self.renderWindowInteractor.SetUseTDx(True)`. It runs and `print(self.renderWindowInteractor.GetUseTDx())` gives me a true later,I think that VTK_USE_TDx was true when the code was compiled